# Android layout: how position layout children at center of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

My goal is to have the form with background white at center of the screen. Just followed some other answer on SO but I cannot achieve my goal.

Only if I remove the background white the Layout goes at center. But, I have the image on background, so I need (and I want learn!) insert a white background to help user.

Thank you very much

[image]

This it the activity_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center" >


            <EditText android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/username"
                />

            <EditText android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/login"
                android:onClick="performLogin" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is styles.xml

```
<resources>



    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    </style>

</resources>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the tag `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` to your LinearLayout to center vertically.